# Whats wrong with ggplot bar chart fill?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a ggplot bar chart, and to create different colored fills for some bars.
I copied from somewhere the code, but with my data it just deosnt work.

Here is the code:

```
df <- data.frame(cat  = c( 0,  1,  2,  3, 4),
                 perc = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 0),
                 mark = c( 0,  0,  0,  1, 0))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df) + 
  aes(x = cat, fill = mark, weight = perc) +
  geom_bar()
```

But the result is a colorless chart, with this warning message:

```
The following aesthetics were dropped during statistical transformation: fill
ℹ This can happen when ggplot fails to infer the correct grouping structure in the data.
ℹ Did you forget to specify a `group` aesthetic or to convert a numerical variable into a factor?
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `aes()` is an argument, not a function, so it needs to be within either the `ggplot()` statement or in `geom_bar()` - e.g. `ggplot(df, aes(...)) + ...`

Comment: @AndrewGustar that's not true. `aes` _is_ a function. The output of the function is normally passed to the `mapping` argument of `ggplot`, but it doesn't have to be. Try `ggplot(mtcars) + aes(wt, mpg) + geom_point()` for example. Works fine.

Comment: OK, I tried that, but the result and warning are the same...

Comment: @AllanCameron Thanks! You learn something every day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `geom_bar` uses `stat_count` by default, so it simply counts up the number of rows at each value of `cat`. This summary doesn't know what to do with the `fill = mark` part of your mapping, since there could be multiple values for `mark` in each category. In your case this isn't obvious because there is only one value for `fill` at each value of `cat`, but the same principle applies; if you are using a grouped summary function then you cannot have a row-wise `fill` variable.

My guess is that you are looking for `geom_col`

```r
df <- data.frame(cat  = c( 0,  1,  2,  3, 4),
                 perc = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 0),
                 mark = c( 0,  0,  0,  1, 0))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df) + 
  aes(x = cat, fill = mark, y = perc) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Or if `mark` is a category rather than a continuous value, use `fill = factor(mark)`

Comment: This is indeed the graph i intended to produce. Thanks.